# Symfony: How to use configuration parameters in a service class?

Tags: symfony

I want to use the parameters in `parameters.yml` in my service class `mailer`
but I got this error while instantiate the mailer class:

```
$mailer = new Mailer();
```

knowing that the parameters are defined in `parameters.yml`:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for AppBundle\Service\Mailer::__construct(), called in

```
namespace AppBundle\Service


class Mailer
{
private $mailer_user;
private $mailer_password;
private $mailer_name;
private $mailer_host;
public function __construct($mailer_user, $mailer_password ,$mailer_name ,$mailer_host)
{
    $this->mailer_name = $mailer_user;
    $this->mailer_password = $mailer_password;
    $this->mailer_user = $mailer_name;
    $this->mailer_host = $mailer_host;
}
//.....
}
```

**services.yml:**

```
mailer:
    class:    'AppBundle\Service\Mailer'
    arguments:    [%mailer_user%, %mailer_password% ,%mailer_name% ,%mailer_host%]
```

Comment: You should specify what error you get (some exception or what?) because "_doesnt work_" is not enought. PS: you should remove the dollar sign from the parameter value and from the service argument `%$mailer_host%` (is this a typo?).

Comment: @gp_sflover is it the right way to do it ? error =>Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: Why are you repeating the mailer parameters in services.yml?  Or is that just some kind of copy/paste thing?

Comment: @Cerad thanks again for your help i removed the repaeated parametrs but i got a new error if you can help me

Comment: @Achraf you should not change the question when it has been resolved  (with a novice it could be a never-ending question :-)) but open a new one for each NEW issue.

Comment: @gp_sflover the questionis is how can i use the parameters in parameters.yml in my service class. it's not yet resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn "*how can I use the parameters in `parameters.yml` in my service class*" (*and to see how a service can be used in a Symfony app*) just read the Symfony docs **paying attention to the Symfony version of the documentation you are reading**:

- [Introduction to Parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html)
- [How to Set external Parameters in the Service Container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html)
- [Service Container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)

BTW you should never instanciate a service class directly like you did:

```
$mailer = new Mailer();
```

but retrieve the service instance from the Service Container (*Symfony will take care to automatically inject all the configured dependancies*) like we usually do in a Controller (*the example below access the Service using the shortcode provided extending the base Controller provided by the FrameworkBundle included in the Symfony standard version*):

```
$mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');
```

Comment: This was solid advice while it lasted, however using '$this->container->get('mailer')' is deprecated now and is dropped in symfony 4. They want you to use [DI](https://symfony.com/blog/the-new-symfony-3-3-service-configuration-changes-explained) in stead.